# How to use regex as dictionary's key?

Tags: python, regex

I've to treat a file using a python script. The file is an automatic creation so some character can be added before and after the key. So I wanna use regex to match them (the middle part is always the same and their is any trouble to do it):

```
def dict(x):
 return{
  '.*key1.*': 'blabla',
  '.*key2.*': 'thing'
 }.get(x,'default')
```

This is not working because `".*"` represent character.

How can I do to perform this?

Comment: No, you can use strings are key, but why not use just as `key1` - btw for regex string use prefixed `r` string literals

Comment: The file I wanna treat is create without any control from me. So as I said, character can be print before and after the "real" key. If is only use key1 or key2 the dictionnary doesn't match

Comment: Romain I misunderstood you question, @mskimm also posted a good trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the file yourself. `get` can't do that for you.

What you want might be something like

```
def get_content(filename):
    lookup = (
        (r'.*key1.*', 'blahblah',),
        (r'.*key2.*', 'thing',),
    )
    for pattern, content in lookup:
        if re.match(pattern, filename):
            return content
```

There are multiple things here that can be optimised, but the idea is there.

---

Edit:

As pointed out by mskimm and Grijesh Chauhan, the code attached in the question has two additional problems that need pointing out:

- Do not use `dict` as a function or variable name since it is the name of a [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).
- For regular expression patterns, use *raw string literals* (literals with prefix `r`, `r'like this'`) instead of standard string literals (`'like this'`) since regex patterns use characters that require escaping way too often.

The code in this answer reflects the above two points.

Comment: you correctly get the question I didn't, you may like to add also tow points 1. Don't use dict as function or variable name it is inbuild type. 2. For Regex use `r` prefix string liters as I have delete my answer.

Comment: Yes you're right pointing them out. I'll edit the answer to add them.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, How about using this `RegexDict`

```
class RegexDict(dict):
    import re
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.update(*args, **kwds)

    def __getitem__(self, required):
        for key in dict.__iter__(self):
            if self.re.match(key, required):
                return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key) # redundancy but it can handle exceptions.

regex_dict = RegexDict({'.*key1.*':'blabla', '.*key2.*':'thing'})

print regex_dict['foo_key1_bar'] # blabla
print regex_dict['foo_key2_bar'] # thing
```